# Spikes in voltage rails

Tags: voltage-regulator

My circuit has 3 sections. The supply is 9V.

This goes to a regulator (5V), another regulator (3V) and the 9V is connected directly also to a BLDC. Now, when I start the motor (this is done in brake with braking action), I see some curves, something like capacitor charging up. I have 2000μF aluminum electrolytic cap in the voltage rail as well.

Even when I remove that, I see these spikes. So there must me some parasitic caps that seem to be charging and discharging. I then inspected the regulator o/p. Both the regulator o/p inductor showed immense noise (the voltage transients was almost 1.5V, and it was existing throughout the motor operation).

The circuitry:

The regulators are:

[image: 9V- 5V regulator]

[image: 5V to 3.3V]

[image: LiFePo4 charger chip]

[image: Controller to BLDC circuitry]

The images in order are:

1. 9V- 5V regulator
2. 5V to 3.3V
3. LiFePo4 charger chip
4. Controller to BLDC circuitry

How do you want me to show the layout/PCB? How can I sort this out? Is the motor action causing spikes back into my circuit to make the ground noisy?

Comment: Circuit diagram and PCB layout is almost mandatory in these situations. Also what test equipment you are using and power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Andy is right we need more info but if I had to take a shot in the dark it's back EMF from the motors (highly inductive load) and you need flyback (or sometimes called snubber) diodes to dissipate this. Read this pdf as it explains it in greater detail:

http://www.eao.com/global/en/Downloads/technical_articles/EAO_TA_Inductive-Loads.pdf

Comment: Hello Sir,

I have edited my question with circuit snippets. Also, regarding snubber circuits- I am basing my designs on hobbykings's ESCs for BLDCs. They do not have snubber circuits. So I did not use them either.

Comment: In case I  use a diode, it is connected between each of the windings and ground. Right.

Comment: Just place the diode over the coil winding. Diode cathode should be directed to the + side of the coil.